# Why does the control key get "stuck" when debugging in VS2010?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-2010

Sometimes the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key gets stuck somehow during debug sessions in Visual Studio 2010, and when I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to stop debugging, it gets reset (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>).

This gets very frustrating sometimes, especially when the solution builds a significant amount of time. How do I prevent this from happening ever again?

---

I just figured out this happens when I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Something</kbd> and the error message appears right after that telling me I can't do that (not pressing the keys, but the result of the combo, like cutting some code or commenting).

---

Posted a [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/776361/ctrl-key-stuck-after-doing-illegal-action-while-debugging#details).

---

As you can see from the bug report page linked to right above, this issue is not likely to be fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This bug was reported in Microsoft Connect on [September 2010](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/604552/ctrl-modifier-becomes-stuck-in-certain-situations)
and reported as "solved in the next major release of Visual Studio".

Nevertheless, the bug was reported again on [August 2011](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/685741/ctrl-key-stuck-during-debugging),
and this time Microsoft was "unable to reproduce the issue".

To my way of thinking, there are two actions that you can take already:

1. Report the bug again on Microsoft Connect with exact instructions on how to reproduce.
2. As a workaround, remove or replace in the meantime the Crtl-Shift-F5 keyboard mapping.

Comment: I posted a [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/776361/ctrl-key-stuck-after-doing-illegal-action-while-debugging#details), let's see what happens.

Answer (score 4):

Because Visual Studio tracks the control key state using keyboard events, rather than checking it when responding to an event.

Therefore if the KeyUp event for the control key is sent to some other window, and that window swallows the event (marks as Handled), VS2010 will not receive the event notification, then the application will behave as though the ctrl key is still down until you press and release ctrl again (which will cause a keyup event).

This is pure conjecture based on the behavior I've seen (and your observations as well), so I don't know why I am bothering to post this...

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but maybe this answer will help someone else.

Problem:  Control key appears "stuck" in VS.  Works fine in other apps.  Pressing Ctrl key does not toggle back to non-Ctrl mode.  For example, arrow up scrolls page instead of moving cursor.

To reproduce: Ctrl-V to paste into read-only source while in debug mode.

To fix: Press right Ctrl key.  Somehow that seems to un-stick it when the left Ctrl key won't.

Comment: It's not old. It's exactly one month since it was posted and I'm checking every day. Also you can fix this by pressing `Ctrl+Shift` which changes the language (where available).

Answer (score 1):

i have reproduce this issue in VS2010,
Steps are
1. Start Debugging
2. Click ctrl+x to cut a line in locked pages
3. It will not let you change
4. Now, Click x,s,tab,Shift+F5 and you will find the error